# wait until insertAdjacentHTML is done then continue code

Tags: javascript

I dynamically add content to my web page using `insertAdjacentHTML` like the following example code:

```
...
for(let i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++)
{
    someDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div id='post-${i}'>...</div>`);

    let insertedObject = document.getElementById(`post-${i}`);
    // at this point `insertedObject` is null!
}
...
```

but content does not get added instantly and `insertedObject` is null, now I have tried finding fixes and the most common is to put a `setTimeout` to wait until the new element is added but thats too slow! could there be a better way to get the newly added element?

Comment: It's not clear why you're doing this - `insertedObject` will be changed on each iteration which makes it mostly pointless. Is there code missing from this question?

Comment: @Andy my problem is that `insertAdjacentHTML` does not instantly add the elements and it takes a while for the element to be added, thats why when i look for the object i just added via `insertAdjacentHTML` it results to `undefined`

Comment: I agree with @Andy that you should provide a little more context on the "why" you need to use insertAdjacentHtml in a loop. This may be an x y problem and maybe it could be just done totallt differently.

Comment: DOM operations operations are not perfectly synchronous and frop what I know there is no way to "await" them because the function itself is synchronous but the DOM is updated asynchronoulsy I believe.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/lecuzajehe/1/edit?html,js,console — I can't reproduce the problem. `insertedObject` is **not** `null`.

Comment: @Peterrabbit — DOM operators are perfectly synchronous, at least when it comes to inserting images. There may not have been a repaint, an image inside the HTML may not have downloaded, but the element *will* be inserted into the DOM.

Comment: I concur that to my knowledge DOM operations are really synchronous. My wild guess is that `someDiv` host DOM node from the snippet is not in the document at the time of `document.getElementById` call, so it cannot be found by that.

Comment: @Quentin Sometimes I had situations where dom operations can seem asynchronous, it's not really asynchronycity but for example when you update the dom in a loop it can be some kind of shift that give that impression.  This is due to the js event loop and the render refreshing frequency. Here is an article about that https://macarthur.me/posts/when-dom-updates-appear-to-be-asynchronous

Comment: @Peterrabbit nice interesting article. Just IIUC it points out scenarios when rendered state (what you see on the screen) does not match internal DOM representation (what JavaScript sees), what is not precisely OP's problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from mine and Peter's comments here's how I might approach this.

Create a containing element. Let's assume that you want it to catch click events from the HTML you're about to insert ([event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/)). Add a listener to it that, for example, calls a function that logs the id of the clicked post.

Then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array to produces an array of HTML strings that you then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) up, and then use `insertAdjacentHTML` to add that HTML to the container.

```js
// Create the container and add a listener to it
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// `map` over the array to create some HTML strings, joining
// them up when the iteration is complete
const html = arr.map(n => {
  return `<div class="post" id="post-${n}">${n}</div>`;
}).join('');

// Add the HTML to the container
container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

// When the container catches an event fired from
// a child element, check that it's an element with
// a post class, and then log its id
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.post')) {
    console.log(e.target.id);
  }
}
```

```css
.container { width: 50%; }
.post { background-color: lightgray; margin: 0.25em; padding: 0.25em; }
.post:hover { background-color: yellow; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```